# Apache ReWrite Rules with header info

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

APACHE 2.2

Ive been trying to redirect a user from a http: page to a https: page.

I have been successful except for when I need to pass along header information in the request.

For example here is a copy of my working rewriteRule that does NOT pass header info

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)loginpage\.action$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/webstore/loginpage.action [R=301,NC,L]
```

What I want to be able to do is to get the two to work together. Have a rewriteRule that not only moves to https but also passes along the header.

My current attempts seem to break the rule all together.

ex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)wishList\.action(.*)$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/webstore/wishList.action$2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any help would be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out my own issue. For some reason the NC which to my knowledge just made the redirect non case sensitive, was what was causing the issue.

New rewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)wishList\.action$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/webstore/wishList.action [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Also note that changing the request type from a 301 to a 307 allows for the call to re-post the data. Which also can cause issues when dealing with dropped parameters.